# XHTML pages, view content within the <head> elements

Tags: xml, xhtml, firefox-developer-tools

.XHTML pages on the server, when check their source with firefox developer tools, the pages show only content inside body,  but does not show HTML elements and stylesheets. The same when download page. Are they added dynamically? Is it possible to retrieve and view content within the 'head' elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
<head>
<title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that XHTML document served with MIME type `text/html`? Or with `application/xhtml+xxml`? Or with `application/xml`? What is the tag for `xslt` referring to?

Comment: the files on server have .xhtml extension. The examples of complete final files (pages in epub) that I have, contains headers as I specified. xslt tag propably by mistake.